# Catch the output of child process' child process by subprocess module

Tags: python

I'm using Popen.communicate to test students' programs.  I found an annoying fact, that this API might not be able to catch output of child process's child process.

For example, one student wrote some code like this

```
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        pwd(cwd);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int ReturnCode;
        while (pid != wait(&ReturnCode))
        {
            ;
        }
    }
```

And pwd() simply prints the current directory

```
void pwd(const char *cwd)
{
    //printf("Current working directory is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", cwd);
}
```

My testing script simply couldn't get any output by using Popen.communicate.  As programs that do not use multiprocess could pass my test script.  I guess the only reason of the problem would be Popen.communicate some how couldn't get the output of a child process's child process.

Is there any walk around for this?

Edit:

This is my testing script

```
cd_command = '''cd /etc
pwd
cd /var
pwd
'''
def test_cd_pwd(self):
    # self.sh is the process that we are testing.
    self.out, self.err = self.sh.communicate(self.cd_command)
    self.assert_(self.out = "/etc\n/var\n")
```

Comment: You might want to paste the python you tested too.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this here; the following worked for me:

guilty.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        printf("Hello from child.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int ReturnCode;
        while (pid != wait(&ReturnCode))
        {
            ;
        }
        printf("Goodbye from parent.\n");
    }
}
```

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(['./a.out'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print "out:", out
print "err:", err
```

output of `./test.py`:

```
out: Hello from child.
Goodbye from parent.

err:
```

I also tried:

- printing without newlines in `guilty.c`
- running `Popen()` with `shell=True`

In all cases, `out` contained the output of both processes.